# Conflicting UI/UX elements - Slider with Stepper buttons on each side

Tags: usability, interaction-design, mobile, user-behavior, buttons

In one of my iOS mobile apps I’m showing a screen with 2 options for ***pasued video scrub***.

At this point, the video is **paused**, I'm giving the users an option to examine the video, either using fast scrub, or frame by frame. The options are:

- **Fast scrub using slider** - similar to all music apps, giving the user the option to fast-scrub thru the video.
- **Step forward buttons** - on each side of the slider, I'm placing button for one-frame-forward and one-frame-forward.

**This are the options I've tried:**

[image]

There are couple issues I can't figure out.

The Slider thumb has to be circle. When using circled button on the sides/below, it's just cause confusing (too many circles).

When placing text-only-button below the Slider, it looks like indicators to where each sider-side doing, it's not clear it's buttons.

Bottom line - Slider with Stepper on each side.
       What do you recommend as good practice? 
**What Love to hear your thoughts, Thanks!**

---

**UPDATE:**

**After a lot of tryouts, that's what I came up with. I've used Gestalt principles as guidelines.**

**What do you think?**

[image]

**OR**

[image]

Comment: Can I ask; where are the play/pause controls on the app? It would possibly make more sense to have the prev/next frame options in close proximity of that...

Comment: Are those conclusions from a test or your own assumptions?

Comment: @SocratesKolios There are not play/pause buttons. In the first step, the video is played on a loop, when the users selected a video, it's automatically paused, giving him the option to pick a frame.. So above the scrub/buttons components we have the video, and that's it. The components(scrub/buttons) are at the bottom of the screen

Comment: @jazZRo Assumptions. But there is logic so I guess it's some what worth the discussion.

Comment: @SocratesKolios I've updated my question with another solution. What do you think?

Comment: @jazZRo I've updated my question with another solution. What do you think?

Comment: Concerning contrast, the white buttons are better. Have you tried a red border and white text for the buttons? And if the slider handle is solid red, why not the buttons? But keep an eye on contrast levels, especially for text.

Comment: @RoiMulia Your original design i.e the line with the dot is quite minimalistic and there is an allure to that. I think the two buttons you have now at the bottom that say "Next/Prev frame" take something away from this design.

Since the concept of your app is quite simple (and to take aesthetics into consideration) have you considered just using two icons without any text (or with a smaller label) and letting your users explore the functionality?

Again, I am only suggesting this because the concept of the app is quite straightforward.

An example: http://i.imgur.com/06ymh7c.png

Comment: @jazZRo Thank you for your suggestion. Thats why I've added the white option. + In terms of "importance", the fast scrubbing is the primary action within this page, the  bottom steppers are secondary action, as they are only for small adjustment. Keeping the buttons white might be a good idea. The only issue is that they look like a plain text and not buttons... What do you think?

Comment: @SocratesKolios Thank you so much for the thoughtful answer. It's funny that you mention that. I had only buttons only for quite few versions, but my new focus is USABILITY. I know Icons only are better in terms of UI, but straightforward text is way clearer, and reduce the cognitive overload(in my opinion). So, in case USABILITY/ACCESSIBILITY is the "way we go", what you would recommend? :) Thank you for your deeply-thoughts answers!

Comment: @RoiMulia hahaha you are absolutely right! This is a UX forum after all and yes we should strive for accessibility and usability. Kinda ignoring my own profession here in a way heh. To be devil's advocate though, keep in mind on straight-forward functions a simple approach often works. Think of the Netflix or YouTube mobile players.

Now, ignoring the dribbbler in me. Have you considered a combination of icons + labels? That might be another solution. 

Again an example: http://i.imgur.com/g4UvrP8.png

Comment: @SocratesKolios I've thought about that as well :) Don't you afraid it'll look like a plain text? That's why I've added the borders. So the question is basically wether we want to add the borders or not (regardless the inside content). What do you think? ;)

Comment: @RoiMulia I think you need to give your users a bit more credit. If the text is close to the icon then contextually it makes sense. Do you think that in this example it looks like plain text? https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*MIJ7FEYpOJob-7C9M-RtjQ.png

You can also play with the positioning if you are not satisfied... Overall I'd say you've reached that point where you start having questions that only your users can answer. Make a few different versions, test them. See which one works better. Actual feedback will always trump academic knowledge in UX.

Comment: @SocratesKolios Can you edit the link? It's showing me a broken url

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/xDN1TYZ.png. We kinda turned this into a chat which is a no no. Anyhow, I hope the above helped! Consider testing your solutions :)

Comment: @SocratesKolios Was pleasure discussing with you. I'm going to actual test this and decide. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Just realised this was posted 6 months ago! Sorry to bump it up.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXKHSO.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Any reason the slider and the advance buttons need to be together? What about incorporating them into the video display?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, giving the user more control over the frame skips, with clear labels...

[image: Skip Frames]

Comment: I don't want to overload the UI. I did gave the user the option to "continuous tap" to exclude the need to retap each time. As swell, Skip Frames might be referred as a button tho to is color. What do you think?

Comment: Only in paused mode, you stated, hard to offer functionality, without putting functional buttons on the UI.

Comment: Maybe changing the SKIP FRAMES to lower case(or maybe capital for each word) and turn it white, might be better?

Comment: Just to emphasize the buttons more, I'm using the theme-color only for clickable objects

Comment: I've updated my question with another solution. What do you think?

Comment: Looks good, might do well to do some user testing.

Comment: I would go one step beyond that. 1 frame, 10 frames, 100 frames. Or something similar. 88px touch targets (ios guidelines) on a 750px screen give an accuracy of maximum 10 touchable items. If you slide your finger very carefully a bit more accuracy, lets say 30 because that works well with 30fps. (This means if your vid is 1 second long, your accuracy will be 1 frame) a minute long video, hardly excessive, would mean you'd have to tap about 60 times +1, or 20 times +3, or... 5 times +10 and 5 times +1.